# How to visually (side by side) view a patch generated by Mercurial Queues on a repo?

Tags: mercurial, diff, patch, mercurial-queue

I use a Mercurial Queues to create patches while I work on the repository.

So, let's say after I'm done with a patch, I do `hg qrefresh` and export the patch to some file I want.
So, now I have a patch file.

How do I view this visually view this patch, side by side , to know the changes I made to the original file(s) in the repository?

I know of one direct way: Keep copies of all the files before I edit and use `kdiff3` or `meld` when I'm done. But this is clearly very time consuming and not straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you still have the patch in MQ you can do a side-by-side view using the [ExtDiff](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ExtdiffExtension) extension, which you already have installed but probably not enabled.

Then you'd:

```
hg extdiff .... -r revision_before_patch -r revision_including_patch
```

On the other hand if you want to be able to do it from just original files and a .patch file you'll need to find a diff program that takes an original and a patch instead of an original and a result.  My (old!) favorite is [xxdiff](http://xxdiff.sourceforge.net/local/doc/xxdiff-patch-UNFINISHED.html).